# How do I access the second brackets in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to coding and am currently learning 2D arrays, I just learned about using curly brackets in the second part of the 2D array, but I don't know how to access and use the numbers in the curly brackets. What I'm currently working on looks like this,

```
array[1] = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
array[2] = new int[]{3, 7, 34, 57};
```

I want to know how i can access the numbers in the curly brackets, so i can set them as variables. for example, use the number as a value for an array

for example, `new int[]{2}` will get the value of `array[2]`

I hope this doesn't sound too dumb and you can understand my question

Comment: array[1][0] = 1 or array[1][2] = 3 or array[2][3] = 57 etc... ?? Is that what youre asking?

Comment: yes, those were the values i was trying to get! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[3][5];
        array[1] = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        array[2] = new int[]{3, 7, 34, 57};

        System.out.println(array[1][0]);
        System.out.println(array[1][1]);
    }
}
```

If you want to access the element `1`, you should access it as `array[1][0]`.
If you want to access the element `2`, you should access it as `array[1][1]`.
If you want to access the element `57`, you should access it as `array[2][3]`.
Note that array Indexes are starting from `0`.

check [this](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html) for learn more about java 2D arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can also fill your 2D array like this:

```
int[][] array = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {11, 22, 33, 44}, {111, 222, 333, 444} };
```

One way to loop through and utilize the elements (rows and columns) of your Two Dimensional Array you can use two **for** loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length {
    // Accessing row i.... 
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        // accessing Column j in Row i... 
        int value = array[i][j]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over through the 2d array if you don't know the rows and columns values and also it is  not equal  try this :

```
   public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        int a[ ][ ]={{3,4,5},
                    {6,7,8},
                    {3,5}};
        for(int i = 0;i < a.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j< a[i].length;j++) {
                System.out.print(a[ i] [j ]);
            }
            System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scroll down for TL;DR if you don't care about why/how**

You can visualize a 2D array in Java as an array of arrays, but let's start with a 1D array, such as

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

This is a simple array of integers (known as `int` primitive type in Java).

By declaring your `arr` variable (this is just an arbitrary name and could be anything, like `blah` even) as type `int[]` you're saying that you want an array of integers.

To get a 2D array of integers, let's first visualize a 2D array in Java, which is actually an "array of arrays", like this,

```
int[][] arr2d = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
}
```

So `{1, 2, 3, 4}` represents your first array, and this is the first item of your outer array, while `{5, 6, 7, 8}` is the second item in your outer array. 
To get those arrays for printing or storing in a variable, you'd use,

```
int[] my1stArray = arr2d[0]; // gives you {1, 2, 3, 4} stored in my1stArray

int[] my2ndArray = arr2d[1]; // gives you {5, 6, 7, 8} stored in my2ndArray
```

Now, you index those just like you always have done before, simply like

```
my2ndArray[2] // gives you 7
```

So 2D array is nothing but an array of arrays, so combining the 2 levels/dimensions, you'd do

```
arr2d[0][0] // gets you 1 stored in {1, 2, 3, 4}
arr2d[1][3] // gets you 8 stored in {5, 6, 7, 8}
```

[Java Arrays Explained](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

**TL;DR**

```
int[][] arr2d = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
}
arr2d[0][2] // gives you 3 from {1, 2, 3, 4}, so 1st array, 3rd item.
```